# Cubic nature of van der Waals' gas equation

Tags: kinetic-theory, gas, states-of-matter, liquid-state

> $V_m^3-\dfrac{RT+bP}{P}V_m^2+\dfrac{a}{P}V_m-\dfrac{ab}{P}=0$

So, At $T<T_c$ the above equation has three real roots say $V_1,V_2,V_3$, my doubt is what does this mean physically because for some particular pressure and temperature gas must have a fixed volume , so what does these three roots mean.

Comment: They don't really mean anything. When the graph of an isotherm of the pressure as a function of $V^{-1}$ has more than one critical point (or, when you have more than one solution to your equation), one has to apply the [Maxwell construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_construction) to replace part of the graph by a plateau, otherwise one gets physical incorrect properties (violation of thermodynamic stability, in particular).

Comment: It is possible to interpret parts of the removed piece of the isotherm as describing metastable states, although such an interpretation of metastable states is in fact incorrect in short-range systems.

Comment: Note that all this is discussed on the wikipedia page for the [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unphysical region of Helmholtz free energy for Van der Waals gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395678/) or [Liquid gas phase transition: question on convexity of free/gibbs energy and maxwell construction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377451) or [Van Der Waals model for liquid gas phase transition : Understanding Maxwell construction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/378123).

Comment: Cross posted on [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/165212/cubic-nature-of-van-der-waals-gas-equation).  Cross posting is strongly discouraged and should ideally be noted in the question itself.